# How does Carter cause Jarvis to get released?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agent-carter

Watching Season 1, Episode 3 of Agent Carter.  In one scene, when Jarvis is brought in for questioning, Agent Carter intercepts her boss just as he's going into the interrogation room.  She states that she accidentally picked up his stolen car file, and at that point Jarvis stands up and states that unless he's charged, he's leaving.

How did Agent Carter picking up the stolen car file cause Jarvis to get released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the agents had been claiming that they did not have the stolen car report that Jarvis claimed he had filed.

Without that they could claim that Jarvis was lying about everything and pressure him into incriminating himself.

When Carter says out loud that they do have it Jarvis knows that the agents have nothing and were lying to him. So he challenges them to charge him or let him go.

Since they don't have anything they have to let him walk.

Comment: I must have missed the part about saying they didn't have the report, but that would explain it.  Thanks!